# MariaDB 10.1 suddenly slow and using near 100% user% cpu and hardly any iowait%

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

Hi I have a single MariaDB 10.1 node running on Debian 8.

Today after months of stability, it has become 20 times slower, and `top` is showing that >99% is used in `user%` and <0.3% is used in `iowait%` (during normal operation our iowati% is more like 5-6%, and user% was more like 50-70%)

The service provider have tested the node and the disks and report everything as "better than average".

If you would like any stats let me know which ones and I'll comment them.

Comment: High CPU almost always means a query that needs work.  To find the query see:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog  (In some situations, the performance issue arises once a table gets bigger than some threshold.)

Comment: check slow queries, number of queries at time, number of connections and frequent queries which pulling huge data. You may need to optimize the queries.

Comment: When was the last DATE you OPTIMIZE'd any TABLE?  Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%insert%'; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime%';  so we get some idea related to your data volume per SECOND.